# Como inserir parágrafos e depois reconhecê-los com um textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer para inserir e depois reconhecer no meu código momentos específicos de parágrafo na digitação em um `textarea`.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu textarea.

Eu quero que ao resgatar o conteúdo desse textarea e inseri-lo em outra `<div>` o mesmo divida os parágrafos inserindo cada um deles em um `<p>`.
Então como ficaria no código:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <p>É claro que a adoção de políticas descentralizadoras ainda não demonstrou convincentemente que vai participar...</p>
   <p>A nível organizacional, o novo modelo estrutural aqui preconizado nos obriga à análise da gestão inovadora da qual fazemos parte...</p>
   <p>Assim mesmo, a hegemonia do ambiente político estende o alcance e a importância de alternativas às soluções ortodoxas...</p>
</div>
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu creio que você pode pegar o valor da string da sua textarea e dar um `split` no `"\n"` para dividir as linhas em um `array`. Em seguida, basta percorrer e criar um elemento `p`, inserindo o valor da linha nele, usando um `append` para inserir em `.wrapper`. Como vai usar o `append`, sempre teria que "limpar" o conteúdo dela.

Veja:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');



textarea.addEventListener('input', function () {
   
   var parts = this.value.split("\n");
   
  wrapper.innerHTML = '';
  
  parts.forEach(function (part) {
     var p = document.createElement('p');
     
     p.innerText = part;
     
     wrapper.append(p)
  })
   
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Fiz assim porque você fez questão que fosse com a tag `p`. Porém, se a necessidade é exibir as quebras de linhas, você pode simplesmente inserir o valor do textarea em `.wrapper` e estilizar o mesmo com o atributo `white-space`, com `pre-wrap` ou `wrap`.

Assim:

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
var textarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');


textarea.addEventListener('input', function () {
  wrapper.innerHTML = this.value;

})
```

```css
.wrapper{
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
```

Essa propriedade faz com que o CSS renderize as quebras de linhas que você adicionar no `textarea`.

Observação: No exemplo acima, como usei `innerHTML`, tem que tomar cuidado com XSS Injection. Você pode usar `innerText` opcionalmente, que aparentemente adiciona um `<br />` ao você colocar a quebra de linha no `textarea`

Comment: mas então em trechos em branco há um \n escondido?

Comment: @NicolasS. na verdade, a quebra de linha é um caractere, que pode ser representado por `"\n"` (tem que ser com aspas duplas, com simples não funciona)